# Android Spinner SomeTime didn't work

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-spinner

I am working on the Android application in which i am playing between Spinner and ListView.
I have few values in the Spinner, what i am doing when i select value from the Spinner, add it into the ListView and then removing them from the Spinner. So apparently its working fine, but for some scenario OnItemSelected() didn't trigger. 
For Example i have four value in the Spinner

```
 - Spinner                        ListView

   FirstValue                      Empty at start 
   SeccondVlaue
   ThirdValue 
   Forth Value
```

I have selected First Value, event fire and value removed from Spinner and add into the ListView, it work perfectly fine. So now the situation of spinner and listview is

```
Spinner                        ListView

                            FirstValue
SeccondVlaue
ThirdValue 
Forth Value
```

Now when i selected again the "SecondValue" from the spinner the event didn't trigger and can't delete value from the spinner while if i have selected the "ForthValue" , event will trigger and value will be add in listview. And similarly it didn't work for some other scenario as well. I don't know why its not working.  Here is my activity code.

package com.example.hostel_finance_managment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Add_Budget_Activity extends Activity {
    private Spinner spinner1;
    public ArrayList<String> Spinner_arraylist;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> Spinner_Adapter;
    public List<Members> memobject;

    int counter=0;
    int  clickCounter=0;

    public ListView list;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> List_Adapter;
    public ArrayList<String> arrayListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_budget);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.add_budget_list);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        Spinner_arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayListView = new ArrayList<String>();

        memobject=Members.listAll(Members.class);
        Spinner_arraylist.add("Select your Value");

        for(int i=0;i<memobject.size();i++)
        {
          Spinner_arraylist.add(memobject.get(i).getName());
     //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Name "+memobject.get(i).getName()+" Position = "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        Spinner_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Spinner_arraylist);
        Spinner_Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(Spinner_Adapter);   


        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Listener is fire",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(!(counter==0))
                {   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Name is  ="+spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Seleected Name is ="+memobject.get(position-1).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               arrayListView.add(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                list.setAdapter(List_Adapter);
               Spinner_arraylist.remove(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                }
                counter=1;
               }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });  
        List_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListView)
                {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                  View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                  TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                  text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                  return view;
              }
            };

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after removed or added elements of ArrayList underlying an active Adapter.